# VW Jetta GLI making intermittent grinding noise on launch

Tags: vw, noise, jetta, rattle

I just saw a 2007 GLI with 120,000 kms that I was interested in purchasing today. There were 3 issues that I need help with:

- Upon launching the car (gas pedal floored) I could hear some kind of grinding noise from the mid-rear section. I could not hear it anymore after trying a few times
- The car made a very brief rattling noise every time it started moving (gas pedal pressed normally). The owner said it might be because of the DSG transmission which mimics the behaviour of a stick shifter during depression of the clutch
- There was a kick every time I backed up (gas pedal pressed normally)

I am mainly concerned about the intermittent noise, but thought to throw in the rest just in case. According to the owner the car was parked for a couple of days, so I'm guessing maybe it needed to warm up first but I can't convince myself.

What are the possible causes of the intermittent noise?

Comment: I was a professional mechanic for years and what you have described would be a pass for me.  Just move on.  There are more, with nicer interiors, quiet shifting....you just have to be diligent in your search.  Don't settle for second best.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I could get! Thanks for the mechanic sharp guidance @DucatiKiller. Just so I know this for the future do you think these are signs of a bad transmission?

Comment: @user1936026 FWIW, it was a very well-written question. You certainly gave Ducati plenty of information to work with :) +1

Comment: Yes, you are describing symptoms of a bad transmission.  Certainly there is no way to truly know but given all of the signs you have described I think you are in a position of risk if you buy this vehicle.  I would concerned anytime with grinding, jerking (kick) and the like.  Best of luck.   @LynnCrumbling  Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Do you want to put your comments down as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Bad Universal Joint... Reverse is the gear that you’ll feel it the most.. If the tranny shifts all gears and clutch works!! Your all good.. also check and change the tranny gear oil.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T BUY IT ! I hope you did not buy that GTI three years ago! A grinding noise mid car in a front wheel drive? There is nothing there! It could be a bad transaxle that transmitted the sound to mid car. Or it may be a wheel bearing but they usually make a thumping noise that increases in intervals between thumps as speed increases, or it may be a strut, again they don't usually grind they clang and pop etc. If you are still following this did you find the problem?

Comment: I didn't dig further. The reasoning of DucatiKiller was enough to not buy the Jetta :)